# Suggestion :- Parallelize web service request

Tags: c#, .net

I have a requirement and its certainly not set on a specific method to achieve it.
I need some recommendations, I am fairly new to .NET
I have a scenario,where i have to process records from stage table based on the filename , I am going to have web service that is going to process the records for each file in parallel and set the flag on the stage table as Processed.
Now there is a certain order that they are processed to stage (filename and date).

I would like the web services, even though they process them in parallel i want them to commit the processed flag based on the same order they were processed to stage.

For example, Say i have a stage table, it has 100 record under filename A123 processed at 09:00am to stage and then i have 20 records under filename A124 processed to stage at 09:02 am . Now I have multiple web service requests trying to process these in parallel (For the sake of concurrency). Say A124 finishes processing first and then A123 finishes. I would like the webservice to commit or set the processed flag for A123 first and then A124. Because of the order they were processed to stage .
This is a set scenario and the reason why we want it this way , is how the business flows for us.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "processed to stage"?

Comment: What is your requirement: you first want to process certain records, and only after that is finished, process some others? Or does the order of real processing not matter, it is just the time flag in the table that has to have a certain order?

Comment: unclear what you are trying to do. Show the exact table structure and the expected result

Comment: When i mean processed to stage, these records were loaded to stage around that time. So basically the process of loading to stage, is reading from the files in a directory and loading them to stage. The way its read and processed to stage is by the time the file came in and the filename itself.

Comment: Unfortunately @Steve , I dont have specific structure and the result expected is as desribed. I can try to explain if you have a specific question

Comment: @alangilbi if all your table cares about is a processed flag then why would you care if one commits after another? If ordering matters then you can just commit the start time of the process. Or you can just assign an incremental ID to each batch and change the processed flag whenever its done.

Comment: So, if you have a place where you store the filename and the time it was "processed to stage", you could have a singleton that sits there and waits for the process to complete. When it does, it checks the time the file was added, and if there are no other files waiting, it sets it to Processed. It does this at a frequency you'll need to determine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to process the results of that web service in order. This is made hard by the parallelism because results will arrive out of order (and this cannot be prevented).

You want to solve this by making the service take responsibility for ordering results. That responsibility is misplaced there.

Instead, make the application that calls into the web service take care to process results correctly. When you notice that the processed flag came true, only process the results after checking that all previous calls have also been processed.